# How to recognize Array pattern with C# Encog

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, encog

I made an Encog based ANN to recognize material's spectrum.
I train the network passing more spectrum into matrix.
Example:

```
input[0] = material 0
input[1] = material 1
```

Each vector is of 10000 element,
After the training I want recognize one of material passing from the sensor acquisition.
What is the function to query the encog network?

**UPDATE**

This is the Recognize Function:

```
public void ProcessInput()
{
        try
        {
            IMLDataSet _testInput = new BasicMLDataSet(_inputToAnalize, _annOutput);
            IMLData output = null;

            List<double> transformedMatrixOutputToArray = _annOutput.Select(x => x[0]).ToList<double>();
            foreach (double[] item in _annOutput)
            {
                output = _network.Compute(_testInput[0].Input);
                Console.WriteLine("actual=" + output[0] + @",ideal=" + item[0]);
            }
            int value = GetClosestIndex(transformedMatrixOutputToArray, output[0]);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
}
```

And the function that retrieves the closest value output from the ideal Output:

```
Func<List<double>, double,int > GetClosestIndex = 
        (doublelist, targetvalue) =>  doublelist.IndexOf(doublelist.OrderBy(d => Math.Abs(d - targetvalue)).ElementAt(0));
```

It's correct work in this mode?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Encog's neural network can be queried with BasicNetwork.compute (Java) or BasicNetwork.Compute (C#).  The following example should help.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Hello_World

Comment: Mr.Heaton, it's an honor talk with you.Thanks for your answer. I update the question with the Input that i want recognize. Talk to you later.